# Instagram API: the server doesn't receive data

Tags: instagram

I use this code to get data from Instagram API. The code runs correctly on some servers, but on other servers it doesn't receive data from Instagram API. The "Curl" is enabled in all servers, who knows what happened?

```
<?php
require 'instagram.class.php';
require 'config.php';

// Receive OAuth code parameter
$code = $_GET['code'];

// Check whether the user has granted access
if (true === isset($code)) {

  // Receive OAuth token object
  // Take a look at the API response
  $data = $instagram->getOAuthToken($code);

  if(empty($data->user->username)){
    header('Location: index.php');
  } else {
    session_start();
    $_SESSION['xxx']=$data;
    $user=$data->user->username;
    $ig_id=$data->user->id;

    header('Location: profile.php');
  }

} else {
  // Check whether an error occurred
  if (true === isset($_GET['error'])){
    echo $_GET['error_description'];
  }
}
?>
```

Comment: did you find a solution for your problem? i have same issue don't know what is the problem!

Comment: Yes, the problem was on the server...